# Can't substract datetime and NaT if in columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When I try the code below, I can compute everything in the loop but not substract series. Why?

```
a = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1980', periods=10, freq='1m'))
b = pd.Series([pd.NaT] * 10)
for i in range(10):
    a[i] - b[i]
a - b
```

TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior (Pandas 0.20.1). What is your Pandas version?

Comment: I have 0.19.2 I'll upgrade and tell you

Comment: Solved, thank you! If you write an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find two related (closed) bugs:

- [Different behaviour on two different environments. TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16726)
- [TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood When fitting Non-daily data](https://github.com/facebookincubator/prophet/issues/225)

Upgrading to Pandas 0.20.1+ usually helps